# VIM: how to use `let errorformat` in my specified error message format?

Tags: string, vim, syntastic, errorformat

The linter I'm using outputs errors in the following format:

```
origin:PycodestyleBear (E501):file:/Users/Virtualenv/testme.py:line:2:column:81:end_line:2:end_column:81:severity:1:severity_str:NORMAL:message:E501 line too long (164 > 80 characters)'
```

It is apparent that the format contains several parts:

1. Type of `bear` used
2. Error number
3. File name
4. line number (start)
5. column number (start)
6. line number (end)
7. column number (end)
8. Type of error message
9. Error message itself

I'm writing the plugin of my linter for syntastic, and this is causing issues with the output string, how can I configure it to match the requirements?

I've tried `let errorformat = 'L%l\\:%m'` with no luck

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [Coala's documentation](https://api.coala.io/en/latest/Developers/coala_settings.html), it looks like you can pass:

- the `--json` flag to output JSON (which I hear is now supported by Syntastic),
- or the `--format` flag to define your desired output format.

Comment: the output I've posted is a result of using '--format'. That doesn't answer the question. Also, json cannot be parsed by errorformat. Note that there's no advantage of using json anyways since the output in the log doesn't give the file name, line number, etc. As is the case with '--format' on coala.

Comment: The point of `--format` is to let you define the output however you want it so you simply have to format your output according to a simple `efm` like the classic `%f:%l:%c:%m` which will almost certainly work with: `--format {file}:{line}:{column}:{message}` (maybe with quotes).

Comment: @romainl The problem with `--format {file}:{line}:{column}:{message}` is that it will print `None` for `column` if the corresponding bear (who came up with that name anyway?) doesn't provide column information. Syntastic can deal with that, as well as with JSON, but the way to do it doesn't fit the OP's approach of development by copy & waste.  The bigger problem is that line and column information is 0-based for some bears and 1-based for others.  Syntastic can deal with that too; it's just that you'd have to do it for 100+ bears.  Talk about bearing the weight of being a coder.